# I have a kind of lag in a game that i'am making using unity it's about the ground check

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[When the runner is touching the ground the bool value does not stay true all the period he is on the ground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRQJz.png)

[I made two boxcolliders2D for the runner : One to collide with the ground and the other set as a trigger to check if he is grounded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZxWy.png)

[Here the runner is colliding with the ground but the bool value isn't set as true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hudxy.png)

[I did the same thing for the ground sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLpvM.png)

[But when the speed is equals to 0 it works fine ...and of course it's usless then](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwO0F.png)

[Oh and another thing , wile the ground prefab keeps generating the runner getenter code here stucked at some point....and when he does it's marked that he is grounded .. any idea how to fix the stucking lag? P.S: I tried to change to boxcollider2D size of the ground but it didn't work :(((](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU0pl.png)

Here is the part of code related to ground check(it's supposed to play a nice footstep soundeffect too)

```
 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.tag == "Ground")
    {
        isGrounded = true;
        footSteps.Play();
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.tag == "Ground")
    {
        isGrounded = false;
        footSteps.Stop();
    }
}
```

Maybe if i just show you the whole code you will be able to help me better(I hope my code isn't so messy)

```
public float speed;
public float jumpForce = 10f;
public float speedMultiplier;
public float speedIncreasedMilestone;
private float speedMilestoneCount;

private Rigidbody2D rb;
private Collider2D myCollider;

public Animator anim;
public AudioSource footSteps;
public bool isGrounded = false;



void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

}


void Update()
{
    if(transform.position.x < speedMilestoneCount)
    {
        speedMilestoneCount += speedIncreasedMilestone;

        speedIncreasedMilestone = speedIncreasedMilestone * speedMultiplier;
        speed = speed * speedMultiplier;
    }

   if(isGrounded == true)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed * Time.deltaTime, rb.velocity.y);
        anim.SetBool("Condition",true);
    }
   if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded == true)
    {
        anim.SetBool("Condition", false);
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x,jumpForce);
    }     
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.tag == "Ground")
    {
        isGrounded = true;
        footSteps.Play();
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.tag == "Ground")
    {
        isGrounded = false;
        footSteps.Stop();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: not sure why you put two colliders to the ground. Are both the two colliders on the parent of ground sprite and have the same "ground" tag? maybe when you have speed, it moves upwards slightly making collision only with the upper collider where the tag isnt "ground".

Comment: Besides your movement script isnt clear. Looks like you add velocity to the rigidbody no matter if there is any player input or not. What do you want to achieve here? If you give more explanations and details it would be better.

Comment: First i made a gameobject and call it "floor" and i made the ground sprite his child and i add those two boxcolliders to that gameobject cause i thought that would fix the ground detection lag(but it didn't),.. then i placed it into the prefab (cause it's supposed to generate)......And about the velocity that i add to the rigidbody..it's an endless runner game !!

Comment: if you could share your project somewhere I could have a look. Are your tags correctly set for floor and all of its childs?

Comment: Yes the tags are set correctly

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you encounter this problem (i.e. an action takes more time than desired), there are two strategies you can choose:

1. Check if you can perform the action less frequently
2. Check if you can perform the action more quickly

In this case, it seems like you only need to know if the player is grounded when the player tries to perform a jump. So that's when you'd want to perform a check.

Comment: in order to move the player laterally, he needs to do the ground check in Update(). It is only an if statement so it isnt performance heavy. He isnt raycasting or anything. Besides he also has another problem on the isGrounded not being true the player is grounded.

Comment: Can you guys be more precise ?